# Do I need permission to use the SE API? What if I'm trying to make money with it?

Tags: support, api, mobile-web, business-model

I recently developed a mobile app using the publicly available API of one of the Stack Exchange sites.

Do I need to obtain permission from Stack Exchange before releasing the app to the public? Can I make money from this, or any other app that uses the Stack Exchange API? I am trying to be cautious so that I don't end up being regretful.

Comment: We have a site specifically designed for this topic called [Stack Apps](http://www.stackapps.com/). I've flagged this to have a moderator migrate it, but you might want to check and see if your question has already been answered.

Comment: Wait, you **developed** it, and *now you're asking?*

Comment: This question has been asked an answered on Stack Apps as http://stackapps.com/questions/2507/stackexchaneg-api-for-mobile-app .

Comment: @Kevin Asked by the same OP at the same time I might add...